# Editing profile user Django

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to edit a profile but I got this error 
"DoesNotExist at /blog/edit/, User matching query does not exist."

```
def Profil(request, username):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        base_template_name = 'blog/base.html'
    else:
        base_template_name = 'blog/visitor.html'
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    logged_in_user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user)
    context = {'base_template_name':base_template_name}
    return render(request, 'blog/profil.html', {'user':user, 'posts':logged_in_user_posts})



def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('blog:index')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'blog/edit_profile.html', {
        'profile_form': profile_form })
```

In the urls.py:

```
 url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$',  views.Profil, name = 'profil'),
url(r'^edit/$', views.update_profile, name='edit_profile'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes from `user = User.objects.get(username=username)` line. `get()` function gives only 1 match and if there is no any match it throws `DoesNotExist` error. To solve the problem you will need to use try - except:

```
try:
  user = User.objects.get(username=username)
except User.DoesNotExist:
  # There is no such user, throw 404 or do anything else
```

Comment: Understanding, but, if I am tryingto edit my profile so that I am a user that means the user exsist !!

Comment: print your username and check if it matches with your user's username in the console (runserver) output. Also print `request.user.username` that will show your username. To check match, you can check output of `username == request.user.username`.

Comment: Indeed, it matches with the user's username, even I changed the "user = User.objects.get(username=username)" by user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username) I still can't edit the profile :/

Comment: Does it give and error when using `User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`? Does form for editing profile renders? Or any other errors? What happens when you submit form?

Comment: When I click on the button "edit profile" in the profile it stuck there and in the url it changes from '/blog/<username>' to 'blog/edit'

Comment: Changing to `blog/edit/` is ok, that is the value for `edit_profile`. But what do you mean by 'it stuck there'? Check in developer tools (devtools) the response from page (networking tab in tool).

Comment: I don't get and I really need this to get work ( part of my stduy) please if you can help me here is my e-mail 'imed08@hotmail.fr', send me so I'll send you the project .rar